# Data not stored in vector using lambda as it should

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda

I have created a custom data structure which loads data from the disk, then the data structure class calls a callback function for every loaded object. This is all working fine - I just want to give you some background information.

The actual problem is in the following function:

```
void getData(std::vector<long long> &c) const
{
    c.reserve(myDataStructure.size());
    std::size_t index = 0;

    myDataStructure.forEach([&c, &index] (const long long &data)    //load data
    {
        c[index++] = data;     //line 8
        return true;           //line 9
    });
}
```

The function is pretty simple: it loads all the data from my custom structure and saves it in a vector. To get better performance I reserve the memory at the beginning. Now, when I run the program in gdb it reaches line 8 multiple times but everytime I check the content of `c` it is empty. Do I use the lambda function in a wrong way? Btw: I'm using g++ with optimization enabled

Additional info: The following code is working as expected and I don't really see a difference:

```
void getData(std::function<bool(const MyData&)> f) const
{
    myDataStructure.forEach([&f] (const long long &data)
    {
        MyData d(data);
        //process data
        return f(d);
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for `forEach()`?

Comment: `forEach()` should not be relevant in this case because it is working --> I'm reaching line 8 with correct data so it should be fine but I can paste it if needed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`reserve` *reserves* memory for the vector contents, but does not actually manipulate the vector size at all. So inside the lambda, you're accessing elements of the vector which are not there. You must add them instead:

```
void getData(std::vector<long long> &c) const
{
    c.reserve(myDataStructure.size());

    myDataStructure.forEach([&c] (const long long &data)    //load data
    {
        c.push_back(data);     //line 8
        return true;           //line 9
    });
}
```

Comment: pro question: with the actual vector allocation strategies every implementation has in place, is there even the need to bother with reserve? :)

Comment: @SergeyA I haven't done any profiling, but I'd say there is. The allocation strategies ensure an amortised constant time for insertion, but they mean a logarithmic (or worse) number of reallocations. Allocating memory is not a cheap operation; if you're going to insert a mere 1 mil. elements, the difference between allocating once and allocating ~20 times could show. Not to mention the fact that for a data type less trivial than `long long`, the cost of the moves itself also comes into play.

Comment: @Angew Thank you so much! I even didn't think of this! Thumbs up